# template class no instance constructor

Tags: c++, c++17

I want to be able to make my Wrapper shorter.

I dont want to have to include `decltype(foo)` twice in each line

What is the right way to use the constructor to be able yo call _foo2 like im trying.

```
class Helper {
public:
    Helper(LPCTSTR filename) : _filename(filename) {}
    ~Helper() { }

    template<typename T>
    T CallFunction() {
        return T();
    }

private:
    LPCTSTR _filename;
};

template<typename T> class WrapFuncObj;
template<typename T, typename... Args>
class WrapFuncObj<T(Args...)> {
public:
    WrapFuncObj(Helper* dll, LPCTSTR func) : _dll(dll), _func(func) {}

    T operator()(Args&&... args) {
        return _dll->CallFunction<T>();
    }

private:
    Helper* _dll;
    LPCTSTR _func;
};


class Export {
    Helper _dll{ L"SayHello.dll" };

public:
    WrapFuncObj<decltype(foo)> _foo = WrapFuncObj<decltype(foo)>(&_dll, L"foo"); // works
    WrapFuncObj<decltype(foo)> _foo2 = WrapFuncObj(&_dll, L"foo"); // problem here
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the constructor arguments directly, no need to indirect through another `WrapFuncObj` functional cast. It works the same way as you used it for `_dll`:

```
WrapFuncObj<decltype(foo)> _foo2{&_dll, L"foo"};
```

Just be aware that initialization with parentheses is not allowed for default initializers of data members, you need to use braces.

Comment: Thanks, What if i wanted to create a `operator[]` inside the helper class that returns the `WrapFuncObj` so i would call it like `WrapFuncObj<decltype(foo)> _foo3 = _dll[L"foo"];`

Comment: @werico4026 How would `operator[]` know the type to return?

Comment: im not sure wasnt sure if there was a way to do it, just trying to amke the Export class as clean as i can, and as simple

Comment: @werico4026 There isn't. Types are statically determined in C++. So since `_dll` has always the same type and the argument in the `[]` always has the same type, then `_dll[...]` also always has the same type. That makes it then impossible to return the correct specialization of `WrapFuncObj`. The only thing you could do is let `_dll[]` return a proxy type that has user-defined conversion operators to all `WrapFuncObj` specializations. Then the line would work as shown, but that seems dangerous, because you separate the indexing from the type determination.

Comment: @werico4026 It is not clear to me from your question what the purpose of `Export` as a class is. So it is hard to make alternative recommendations. You could use a non-operator function like `_dll.get<decltype(foo)>(L"foo")` and as long as it isn't in the context of a non-static data member, you would then be able to just use `auto _foo = _dll.get<decltype(foo)>(L"foo");` if you prefer that. But placeholders are specifically not allowed in non-static data members.